# Powershell error message in console is being wrongly indented

Tags: powershell, stdout, windows-subsystem-for-linux, indentation, stderr

What I am trying to do is run the wsl process, get its stdout and stderr channels to print to console as if they were executing normally, throw an error in powershell if stderr and for the printout to be 1:1 as the original.

But I am getting this indentation error:

when running `` wsl.exe echo a 1`>`&2`;echo b 2>&1 `` twice
Powershell's console is being overindented than it should be.
it sometimes even gets so bad that Write-Host output is being indented despite no indentation.
`` wsl.exe echo a 1`>`&2`;echo b 2>&1 ``
[image: Wrong Error indentation]

`` cmd.exe /c echo a 1`>`&2`&echo b 2>&1 ``
[image: Expected Error indentation]
Sometimes this also happens after running a lot of the wsl command above
[image]
further more, when it gets stuck like that it infect other Write-Error calls:
[image]

$PSVersionTable
Name  |Value
----|-----
PSVersion|5.1.22000.282
PSEdition|Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions|{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion|10.0.22000.282
CLRVersion|4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion|3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion|2.3
SerializationVersion| 1.1.0.1
Edit:
[image]

Comment: This is very confusing. You are trying to tell PS to run WSL and get the code it returns and have that code write to the console ?

Comment: this looks like an end of line problem; powershell is still stuck on linux mode of just \n instead of dos mode \r\n

Comment: @dcaz Im running a linux command via WSL, an expected use case. the output of the linux command is by wsl magic later transfered back to powershell and populates the stderr and stdout channels as if they were normal. Powershell is a little tricky in the way it handles those streams to I am just piping stderr into stdout, this results in capturing error output. as intended with powershell. yet it indents the error and does a whole bunch of other weird stuff instead. I am suspecting it somehow pollutes the buffer.

Comment: it looks like you have a tabbed view; are you using the standard windows console, or something like windows terminal? and if not are you getting the same behavior in the console?

Comment: @Gregory It is the same even when run not in windows terminal. (I am running windows 11 so normally now powershell opens in windows terminal but when running as admin it doesn't run under windows terminal.)

Comment: i'm not sure, maybe as a work around you might be able to work a `-replace '[^\r]\n',"\`r\`n"` in somehow?

Comment: even so, it probably wouldn't help since you're still getting the issue in the last screen with only a `write-error`

Comment: @Gregory yep that doesn't work, just tried

Comment: how about `[console]::out.newline = [char[]]@(10,13)`

Comment: actually i guess `[console]::Error.NewLine = [char[]]@(10,13)`

Comment: @Gregory am I supposed to just run this line before executing? because that does nothing at all to the output, further more it doesn't seem to change the variable(tried  [console]::Error.NewLine = [char[]]@(10,13,65) and [console]::Error.NewLine is still 13,10[byte[]][char[]]([console]::Error.NewLine)
13
10
)

Comment: [newline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.newline?view=net-6.0) isn't quite what i wanted it to be it looks it only affects what the textwriter uses to end a line and not whatever's doing the translation from `"\`n"` to `'\r\n'`

Comment: however your best bet is likely to post it as a bug in the console

Comment: in the last frame where `write-error` is giving you grief; what does `write-error "hello\`nworld\`r\`nbye"` do?

Comment: @Gregory adding image to post, sec

Comment: ```Tried this(complete overkill), still indentation... it only indents on the oneliner of wsl
wsl.exe echo a 1`>`&2`;echo b 2>&1 | %{$_ -join ("")} | Tee-Object -Variable output | %{$_ -replace [char]0,""} | %{ $_.trim()}| %{ $_ -replace "`r?`n","`r`n"} | %{Write-Error "$_";}

write-output prints fine and if stored into a variable doesn't indent when later used with write-error  $a = wsl.exe echo a 1`>`&2`;echo b 2>&1 | %{$_ -join ("")} | Tee-Object -Variable output | %{$_ -replace [char]0,""} | %{ $_.trim()}| %{ $_ -replace "`r?`n","`r`n"} | %{Write-Output "$_";};$a | %{Write-Error $_}```

Answer (score 3):

While I have *no explanation* for the behavior, I have a *workaround*:

Enclose the entire command in `(...)` (I've also rewritten the command to make it more obvious what it does, but it is functionally equivalent):

```
# !! The (...) makes the symptom go away.
(wsl.exe bash -c 'echo a 1>&2; echo b' 2>&1)
```

Note:

- Using `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), means that the all output lines from the `wsl.exe` call are collected *up front* before being output to PowerShell's pipeline. That is, you forgo PowerShell's *streaming* behavior of relaying the output lines *as they're being received*. That said, that won't be a problem in practice, *unless* the call at hand emits so many lines that collecting them all in memory would run out of memory or the act of collecting them would cause an unacceptable delay, if (themselves streaming) downstream commands such as `Tee-Object` are expected to produce display output in a timely fashion.

The symptom you're seeing is related to how the formatting system renders the [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances that stderr lines are wrapped in, but *how* the problem occurs and why it only starts surfacing *from the second invocation on* is unclear to me.

---

Two asides:

- That stderr lines (`2`) redirected (`>`) to the *success* error stream (`&1`) *render as errors* is fundamentally problematic.

  - In PowerShell (Core) 7+, this no longer happens (even though the stderr lines are still wrapped in `[ErrorRecord]` instances).
  - To emulate this behavior in Windows PowerShell, call `.ToString()` on each output object:

    ```
    wsl.exe bash -c 'echo a 1>&2; echo b' 2>&1 | ForEach-Object ToString
    ```
- The way PowerShell merges stdout and stderr when `2>&1` is used does *not* guarantee the original output ordering; that is, the above command either may either output `a` before `b`, or vice versa - unpredictably so; see [GitHub issue #5424](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5424).